# Someone apparently tried to XSS Stack Overflow in a post, and my flag was declined

Tags: discussion, flags, questions, specific-question, declined-flags

During a little review on Stack Overflow I saw the following post:

> ```
> function funcLoad() {
>     var frame =document.getElementById("iFrame");
> }
> ```
>
> Sanalkurs

I was going to edit it and saw the [post content the following](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41219df7-91c2-41ee-8828-1592deb9b8a6/view-source):

```javascript
    function funcLoad() {
        var frame =document.getElementById("iFrame");
    }
</script>
<a href="www.sanalkurs.net" target="https://esgm.sgk.gov.tr/Esgm/LoginT.action">Sanalkurs</a>
<iframe name="iFrameadi" id="iFrameadi" onload="funcLoad()" width=450 height=400 src="https://esgm.sgk.gov.tr/Esgm/LoginT.action"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I was confused, because this had [nothing to do with the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975526/iframe-onload-event). Because this looked for me as an amateur try of XSS [I removed this javascript-part](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5256557) and I flagged this (cannot find a way to link this). My flag was declined (I cannot find a link to this either). Because I was worried about the security of SO I flagged this, because I thought this may need more investigation or something.

I think the answer was "evil" in sense it was an attempt to spam and try to XSS Stack Overflow.

Was my flag really wrong?

Comment: It was not about the content of the answer but because it was imho a try of xss/spam.

Comment: @juergend This one did look like it was an attempt to add spam or some malicious code into the answer. I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to say for certain though.

Comment: Given the question, I **think** it may actually have been an attempt at an answer. It is quite a mess, however.

Comment: what did you flag it as?

Comment: @SamIam I am not sure anymore, as explained, I can't find a page or list of given flags

Comment: At first, it seems like an example to the question as `iframe` requires a source. But, the link can be considered as self-promotion/spam/XSS though.

Comment: @omeinusch: Here is a [link to your flag history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2321643)

Comment: I've restored the content but indented the whole post. I'm more convinced it is a (very bad) answer, not a XSS attempt.

Comment: Hmm, Hanlon's razor applies here.  Be sure to use a custom flag and explain what you found when you flag posts like this.

Comment: @HansPassant I used the custom flag and explained: "tries to insert an iframe"

Comment: This looks like a bad attempt to answer the question to me. The question itself uses iFrames. IMHO your edit to remove the code should not have been accepted.

Comment: @AshleyMedway why? Originally the code wasn't visible anyway

Comment: @Templar perhaps I am missing reading the edit log. If the code was incorrectly added to a post then the correct edit in this scenario should be to correctly indent the code for the editor. If the question had nothing to do with iframes then fine flag for moderator attention, but here the post should have been "fixed".

Comment: Ignore anyways? Stack Overflow is the one that needs to be responsible not to be vulnerable to HTML injection, and it usually isn’t. (We did have a couple recently, but if it’s not hurting you…)

Comment: Hehehe. Common of Turkish :-)

Comment: @AshleyMedway: If it can be edited out and is no harm because SO doesn't allow intepretation of HTML in markdown, then edit it out. It can be handled by the community. No need to flag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The timeline of this flag was the following:

- your custom flag with the comment "*tries to insert an iframe*" was submitted 2014-07-09 11:25:41
- you then [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5256557) removing that code about 20 seconds later at 2014-07-09 11:25:56
- the edit was approved roughly 4 minutes later

When I reviewed [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24651867/2) I saw the answer as:

```
function funcLoad() {
    var frame =document.getElementById("iFrame");
}
```

This answer didn't raise any red flags for me and while I'm not a JavaScript expert, I didn't see anything wrong with the code - as a result I declined the flag.

Using a custom flag means that the resolution falls solely on the moderators, even if you hadn't suggested an edit to the answer, your custom message "*tries to insert an iframe*" doesn't provide enough details to fully explain the issue that we need to resolve.

Comment: What would be the correct procedure been? In the event that would have been a "real" XSS attempt?

Comment: "I'm not a JavaScript expert" Basically, assume all JavaScript code is malicious ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @omeinusch at the very least, I'd mention in flag message something like "I just suggested an edit that removes suspicious content" - moderator then could decide to look into post revisions history to find out. Also, I'd probably quote a piece of troublesome text, so that moderator would better see what I mean, like '_iframe name="iFrameadi"_'

Comment: @omeinusch My question to you would be did this situation really warrant a moderators invention?  If so, then what gnat suggests would be correct, include as many details as possible in the custom flag.  IMO, though this didn't seem like a situation that needed us to be involved.

Comment: @bluefeet: If there was a real attempt at an XSS attack then actually I'd disagree and say it does warrant a moderators attention - surely such behavior breaches the rules or guidelines of the site being an attempt to attack the SO community and if such is the case I think discussions with the user/banning should be considered?

Comment: @ian if that is in fact the case, then including those details in the custom flag are critical for us to process it correctly. The details in this flag didn't provide enough info to research that.  When submitting a custom flag it is important to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @bluefeet: yeah OK - totally get that, just wanted to be clear that if there were an attempted XSS attack it is worth a quick investigation. I can sympathize with the lack of information though - frustrates me on a daily basis with bug reports!

Comment: @BoltClock Then you should start to ban everyone posts in Javascript tag :) Maybe after this we can get rid of this "language"